# search in sql database by the query written in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables in SQL database:

buyinvoices :

```
BIId | SeId | TAccount
---- | ---- | --------
2    | 5    | 10000000
---- | ---- | --------
3    | 5    | 50000000
---- | ---- | --------
4    | 2    | 25000000
---- | ---- | --------
5    | 4    | 15000000
---- | ---- | --------
6    | 2    | 12000000

Sellers :

SeId | Name      | Company
---- | --------- | -------
1    | jack      | MSN
---- | --------- | -------
2    | sam       | BBD
---- | --------- | -------
3    | cherry    | HBS
---- | --------- | -------
4    | sam       | BSD
---- | --------- | -------
5    | kevin     | MSN
```

Now, I want to search by three textboxes: `txtBIId , txtName and txtCompany`

> ex1 : txtBIId.text = " "  , txtName.text = "sam" , txtCompany.text =" "

result :

```
BIId | SeId | TAccount
---- | ---- | --------
4    | 2    | 25000000
---- | ---- | --------
5    | 4    | 15000000
---- | ---- | --------
6    | 2    | 12000000
```

> ex2 : txtBIId.text = " "  , txtName.text = "sam" , txtCompany.text ="BBD"

result :

```
BIId | SeId | TAccount
---- | ---- | --------
4    | 2    | 25000000
---- | ---- | --------
6    | 2    | 12000000
```

How can do this search by c# ?

I wrote this code but it didn't work correctly:

```
SqlCommand SCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SCon.Open();
        SCmd.Connection = SCon;
        SCmd.CommandText = "Select * From BuyInvoices Where BIId like N'%" + txtBIId .Text + "%' and SeId in ( Select SeId From Sellers Where Name like N'%" + txtName .Text + "%' and Company like N'%" + txtCompany.Text + "%')";
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DA.SelectCommand = SCmd;
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DA.Fill(DT);
        SCon.Close();
        datagridview.DataSource = DT;
```

I don't know why this only works for `buyinvoices` first row.

Thank You Very Much For Your Help.

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries. [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: What is the error it gave you? Was it a problem with the C# code or with the SQL statement?

Comment: with sql statement, it doesn't work for other rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using parameterized queries. [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

---

This is a **catch-all** style search query, for use with proper parameters.

This would be **much better** if you could use `=` instead of `like '%...%'`

```
select *
from BuyInvoices
where (BIId = @biid 
    or @biid is null)
 and SeId in (
  select SeId
  from Sellers
  where (name like N'%'+@Name+'%' 
      or nullif(@Name,'') is null)
    and (Company like  N'%'+@Company+'%' 
      or nullif(@Company,'') is null)
  );
```

---

Using an `inner join` instead of `in (subquery)`:

```
select bi.*
from BuyInvoices bi
  inner join Sellers s
    on bi.SeId = s.SeId
where (bi.BIId = @biid 
    or @biid is null)
  and (s.name like N'%'+@Name+'%' 
    or nullif(@Name,'') is null)
  and (s.Company like  N'%'+@Company+'%' 
    or nullif(@Company,'') is null);
```

Reference:

- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)
- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)